# Distorted Home Folder Display

Tags: 14.04, display, directory, home-directory

I am using 14.04.3 LTS. Whenever I open my home folder for the first time after my laptop has booted I get the following distorted display, which becomes normal after few moments. How can I fix this?

[http://i.imgur.com/qKkT90P.png](https://i.imgur.com/qKkT90P.png)